# Preparing time series data for building an RNN

Tags: dataframe, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, timeserieschart

I am preparing time series data to build an RNN model (LSTM). The data is collected from sensors installed in a mechanical plant. Consider I have data for input and output temperature of a compressor along with the time stamps.

Like this there is data for around 20 parameters recorded along with their time stamps. Problem is there is a difference in the time stamps at which data is collected.

So how do I ideally match the time stamps to create a single dataframe with all the parameters and a single time stamp?

Comment: Which language are you coding in? Could make the answer more specific...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an RNN doesn't know anything about time deltas but only about time *steps*, you will need to quantify / interpolate your data.

1. Find the smallest time delta `Δt` in all of your series
2. Resample all of your 20 series to `Δt/2`* or smaller ([Nyquist-Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem))

* Actually you'd need to do a Fourier transform and then use twice the cutoff frequency as sampling rate. `Δt/2` might IMHO be a good approximation.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If so, please accept it and give it an upvote. If not, please clarify your question.

Comment: can you explain more on Fourier transform part or can you share any link regarding this.

Comment: For python I'd go with [`scipy.fftpack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/fftpack.html) or [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.fft.html) which has several routines for fft. However I'm not so deep into signal processing. In the end, I don't expect it to have a high influence on your problem. Your RNN-architecture and training will be the crucial part. Focus on that.